# relative link for directory above

Tags: html, relative-url

I've got a file structure like so

```
Root
-index.html
-adirectory
 ->fileinthedirectory.html
```

I'd like to create a relative link from `fileinthedirectory.html` to `index.html` since `/index.html` links to `/adirectory/index.html` which doesn't exist.

Comment: strange you're saying /index.html links to /adirectory/index.html. It should link to index.html under the root of the website.

Comment: My mistake. misread my own file. =/

Answer (score 17, accepted):

To go up one directory you can use:

```
 ../index.html
```

or you can start the URL with a slash to start from the root

```
 /index.html
```

Comment: `..` would be a better link than `../index.html`. Index pages shouldn't be linked directly except when conforming to legacy systems. This is both for SEO and for maintainability, e.g. when all your `index.html`s change to `index.php`s.